# Why are questions regarding software tools migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration

To quote the Stack Overflow FAQ:

> If your question generally covers…
>
> - ...
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - ...
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your
>   question!

I recently had [a question about how to achieve something with the editor Vim](https://superuser.com/questions/333203/why-is-there-a-difference-between-edit-inside-and-in-vim) migrated to Super User. I find this strange, because Vim is a software tool commonly used by programmers. Especially strange, because Vim itself is very programmable and I suspect the audience of StackOverflow would be better suited to answer questions about it and how to program it than the community of Super User (I might be wrong here).

Why are such questions migrated? Is there any other policy that dictates this, that isn't visible to Stack Overflow users?

(I specifically check the FAQ before asking this question, just to be sure)

Comment: FYI, there's no point flagging the question on SuperUser - all we can do is close down the SU copy of the question. If you want the SO copy reopened you'd need to flag the [original](http://superuser.com/questions/333203/why-is-there-a-difference-between-edit-inside-and-in-vim#question), to get a SO moderator to re-open it and clear the migration history.

Comment: Didn't know there was an *original* question still left and couldn't find any option to recommend migrating back to SO. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: No problem. To get to the original post of any migrated question you can just click the website in the text "migrated from *stackoverflow.com* 4 hours ago", and we generally try to avoid re-migrating questions, especially not back to the source site.

Comment: *facepalm* in my first comment the link should have been [original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330835/why-is-there-a-difference-between-edit-inside-and-in-vim?noredirect=1), I managed to link to the SU version by mistake >.<

Comment: You mean avoid here on Meta?

Comment: Erm... I don't think so... What I meant around the work "avoid" is once a question is migrated from SiteA→SiteB we try not to migrate the SiteB copy to a third location or back to SiteA.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Vim is an edge case, in that it's an editor, but one that as a very common (and as you point out, programmable) programmer's tool has earned its place on StackOverflow.

I suspect that your question was automatically migrated by well-meaning users voting to close as off-topic. Hey ho - it'll happen from time to time, as only 5 such users need to vote to migrate.

Comment: Yeah, I even got an answer of how to *program* Vim to solve my problem. :-(